# MVC File upload validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, file-upload

I have a simple situation where I have a page that uploads Files, for some importing.  At the moment, all I have is a file upload input on my page.

this is what my get controller looks like

```
public ActionResult FileUpload()
{
    return View();
}
```

This is what my view looks like

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "FileUpload";
 }
<h2>FileUpload</h2>
<form action="/Home/FileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="newFile" name="newFile" />
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and this is what my post action looks like

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase newFile)
    {
        if (newFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //do stuff here
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

You will of course notice there is no mention of a model here as I cannot find a way to create a model for this situation.  I would like to have some very basic validation, along the lines of 'please choose a file before you upload', thats all.

Is there a way to achieve this?!

Thanks in advance

Will

Answer (score 3):

Create model class with string property newFile and put a Required on it.

In controller accept not HttpPostedFile but your model class.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the client side validation manually:

```
<input type="file" data-val="true" data-val-required="please select a file" name="file" />
@Html.ValidationMessage("file")
```